# Font Awesome and Shopify SSL not working correctly

Tags: ssl, fonts, ssl-certificate, shopify, font-awesome

I'm having a problem getting my SSL to work on Shopify because of Font Awesome.

My Shopify site is using a theme that uses Font Awesome for its fonts. When I try to activate SSL certificates on Shopify I get an error message saying "unencrypted file found on page". After having spoke with one of Shopify's senior technical agents, who was able to review the coding on my site, he was able to determine that the issue is caused by the font from Font Awesome.

This technician says that we need to speak with Fontawesome and see if we can get a secured file.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? If I can do this manually, can someone assist me in setting this up on my Shopify site?

I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Thank you,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Just make it `//` instead of `http://` in the tag where it is mentioned. It'll work.

Comment: Hey HymnZ, just want to say THANK YOU!! I was going crazy trying to figure out how to fix this issue. And your fix worked like a charm!